# Use IF statement on ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

#### Table Structure

```
id int unsigned auto_increment
type int
value varchar
```

#### Data

```
id  type value
1   1   1000000
2   1   20000
3   1   25000
4   1   50000
5   1   25000
6   1   20000
7   1   20000
8   1   50000
9   1   20000
10  1   50000
11  1   50000
12  1   50000
13  1   200000
14  1   20000
15  1   25000
16  1   20000
17  1   25000
18  1   25000
19  1   20000
20  1   50
21  1   20000
22  1   50000
23  1   1000000
24  1   25000
25  1   25000
26  1   50000
27  1   50000
28  1   50000
29  2   a
30  2   b
```

There are two types in the table, if type is 1 value will be number, if type is 2 the value will be string, therefore, If I want to order by value I need to convert value to `UNSIGNED` when type is 1, just order by the letter if type is 2, here is the MySQL script I wrote.

```
SELECT *,
    CONVERT(`value`, UNSIGNED) `result`
FROM `tests`
ORDER BY IF(`result` = 0, `value`, `result`) DESC
```

I use `result = 0` to check if the value is string or number, if result = 0 ORDER BY `value` directly, if not ORDER BY `CONVERT result`, but the output is not exactly order by the `CONVERT result`, if I edit the code to

```
SELECT *,
    CONVERT(`value`, UNSIGNED) `result`
FROM `tests`
ORDER BY IF(`result` = 0, `result`, `result`) DESC
```

The output will be correct, that's mean IF condition is work but the result is wrong, have no idea about that.

#### Dump Query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tests` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `value` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tests` (`id`, `type`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1000000'),
(2, 1, '20000'),
(3, 1, '25000'),
(4, 1, '50000'),
(5, 1, '25000'),
(6, 1, '20000'),
(7, 1, '20000'),
(8, 1, '50000'),
(9, 1, '20000'),
(10, 1, '50000'),
(11, 1, '50000'),
(12, 1, '50000'),
(13, 1, '200000'),
(14, 1, '20000'),
(15, 1, '25000'),
(16, 1, '20000'),
(17, 1, '25000'),
(18, 1, '25000'),
(19, 1, '20000'),
(20, 1, '50'),
(21, 1, '20000'),
(22, 1, '50000'),
(23, 1, '1000000'),
(24, 1, '25000'),
(25, 1, '25000'),
(26, 1, '50000'),
(27, 1, '50000'),
(28, 1, '50000'),
(29, 2, 'a'),
(30, 2, 'b');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple clauses in the order by:

```
ORDER BY type,  -- put numbers first
         (case when type = 1 then value + 0 end) desc, -- convert values to numbers
         value
```

The problem with using one expression, such as `if()` or `case`, is that the result is converted to one type.  So, you are sorting either numbers or strings, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will be very inefficient. But then again the whole table structure is naff. If you have two datatypes in one column, you're doing something wrong!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol . . . What do you mean by "very inefficient"?  The time taken to sort data is not particularly dependent on the number of keys in the `order by`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, actually there are over twelve types, and types are dynamic, therefore I can't make sure which type is string and which type is number, I know it's bad design, but you know, it always happened with many weird reason